# web.xml security: how to get root unrestricted, but all else restricted?

Tags: java, jetty, security, web.xml

i'm looking to have unrestricted access to files on the web server root(the welcome page), but -by default- have restricted access to all urls which are resolving to subfolders.

I'm facing the issue that when using / or /* for restricted access as default match for restricting access, then the root folder can't be made unrestricted anymore. On the root there's the default 'index.html' which i'd like to appear when accessing the domain name. Any advice is appreciated.

By the way, I'm using jetty 6.1.6

This is a snippet of my web.xml file:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>ForbidDefaultAccess</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
  <!-- unauthorized -->      
    <web-resource-name>GrantAccess</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/some_dir/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>      
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>AuthorizedResources</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/cfg/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/fileupload/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/list/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>UserRole</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

White listing is possible in Java J2EE 6

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Disable unneeded HTTP methods by 403 Forbidden them</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <http-method-omission>GET</http-method-omission>
        <http-method-omission>HEAD</http-method-omission>
        <http-method-omission>POST</http-method-omission>
        </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/new_security_features_in_glassfish

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Filter`, applied on all URLS. Make it check the depth of the URL (basically the number of slashes), and allow or deny access to the resource accordingly, using `chain.doFilter()` in the first case, and throwing a `HTTP 403 error` in the second case.

Comment: Would then any entries in the web.xml specifically granting access still work?